# Android: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play

In my Google Play developer console, in the crashes section, I have got some rare occurrences (10 per day, for 50 000 users per day) of the following crash:

I saw similar posts to this question on Stackoverflow but without relevant answer.

Anybody can help?

Thanks !!!

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4584)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:158)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method:0)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method:0)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:985)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:499)
```

Comment: According to the strack trace and the AOSP source, the package manager fails to load your `Application object`. Did you implement an Application subclass and specify it in the manifest `<application>` tag?

Comment: Thanks. It is probably that. I have two classes extending Application but only one of those was mentioned in the manifest (because you can mention just one, not two). Now  one of my Application subclasses extends the other one... (even if it is useless) It will probably fix the issue.

Comment: Have you solved the problem.  I see exactly the same type of crash. It has happened only 9 times out of 300+K downloads.  The app does not have a subclass of Application.